# The probability that a man hits a target is 1/3

Tags: probability

The probability that a man hits a target is  1/3.

a) If he fires five times, what is the probability of his hitting target at least two times?

b) How many times must he fire so that the probability of his hitting target at least once is more than 90%?

I tried to solve it but no success

Comment: Show your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**

Use the binomial distribution:

$$P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$$

**Hint 2:**

You need to find $n$ such that

$$\begin{align*}
P(X \geq 1)
&=1-P(X=0)\\\\
&=1-(1-p)^{n}\\\\
& \geq 0.9
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score -1):

As we know the number of trials is at least $2$ out of $5$. 
So
\begin{align}
&1-{^5C_2} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\\
&=1-\frac{80}{243}\\
&=\frac{163}{243}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this is not a useful contribution. It's just part of an answer to an old question that already has an answer. If you really want to help people, look for new questions you can contribute to. Use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference